# Can VisualState Setter target all XAML controls of the same type?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, visualstatemanager

In a Windows 10 UWP application, can VisualState Setter have a Target value equal to a XAML control type?  For example can you do this to target all the TextBlock font size on the page (kind of like that way CSS works to apply styles on HTML tags)

```
<VisualState.Setters>
<Setter Target="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="{StaticResource SmallScreenFontSize}"/>
</VisualState.Setters>
```

If not, is there a better way to accomplish setting the property to groups of the same controls instead of assigning each control on the page a unique name - which is tedious if there are many on the page.

Should I make a user control for the text block and apply visual state to the user control instead?

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any other way to do this than to copy the control's entire ControlTemplate into a new Style and putting the visual states in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know any option to do that - few months ago I had the same question but unfortunately for now there is no such option to set target XAML control for the Setter.

As BoltClock mentioned one of the best way is to save Control Template as a new Style and then insert Visual States in this template.

You can find how create Control Template below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093(VS.95).aspx

Using above example you can just define specific control with desired behaviour but with custom style.